# Updating a record using RecordDotSyntax results in an error

Tags: haskell, ghc

## Context

If I load the following into [ghc-9.2.1-alpha2](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/blog/20210422-ghc-9.2.1-alpha2-relased.html) which has support for [RecordDotSyntax](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0282-record-dot-syntax.rst):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedRecordDot, OverloadedRecordUpdate, DuplicateRecordFields #-}
----------------------------------------------------------------------
data Point = Point { x :: Double, y :: Double }

instance Show Point where
    show p = "Point { x = " ++ show p.x ++ ", y = " ++ show p.y ++ " }"

p = Point 10 20
```

I can then run the following in ghci:

```
ghci> p { x = 30 }
Point { x = 30.0, y = 20.0 }
```

Cool, it's working!

## Issue

However, if I add the following to my test file above:

```hs
result =
    let
        a = Point 1 2
        b = a { x = 3 }
    in
        b
```

and reload, I get the following message:

```
ghci> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/dharmatech/tmp/test-ghc-9.2.0.20210422/point-update-issue.hs, interpreted )

/home/dharmatech/tmp/test-ghc-9.2.0.20210422/point-update-issue.hs:13:13: error:
    RebindableSyntax is required if OverloadedRecordUpdate is enabled.
   |
13 |         b = a { x = 3 }
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

## What I've tried

If I add `RebindableSyntax` as the message suggests, I get many more errors which look like this:

```
/home/dharmatech/tmp/test-ghc-9.2.0.20210422/point-update-issue.hs:3:27: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Double’
  |
3 | data Point = Point { x :: Double, y :: Double }
  |
```

## Question

Is there a way to get this to work? Or is it something that's just not implemented yet?

## Update 2021-08-10

If I add the following as *alias* and *Ari* suggested:

```hs
import Prelude
import GHC.Records
```

I get the following:

```
point-update-issue.hs:17:13: error:
    Not in scope: ‘setField’
    Perhaps you meant ‘getField’ (imported from GHC.Records)
   |
17 |         b = a { x = 3 }
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: Explicitly `import Prelude`. In the presence of rebindable syntax, GHC doesn't implicitly import it. See here: https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/rebindable_syntax.html?highlight=rebindable%20syntax

Comment: @alias Looks like that got me closer! There are fewer errors now. After adding `import Prelude` I get: `Not in scope: ‘getField’`. I guess I need another explicit import?

Comment: `getField` comes from [`GHC.Records`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-Records.html).

Comment: @alias Gosh, I could have sworn I tested your suggestion above and thus accepted the answer. However, now that I'm trying it again after adding `import GHC.Records`, I'm actually seeing this:
`Not in scope: ‘setField’` followed by 
`Perhaps you meant ‘getField’ (imported from GHC.Records)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. You have enabled `RebindableSyntax`. This allows you to redefine certain behaviour
   by defining certain functions, otherwise imported from Prelude, in the local scope. Therefore, `RebindableSyntax` implies `NoImplicitPrelude`. You need to manually import `Prelude`, optionally hiding functions you want to override.

   ```
   import Prelude hiding (...)
   ```
2. You have enabled `OverloadedRecordUpdate`, an experimental feature from GHC 9.2 that has not yet been stabilized.

   The relevant version of the [GHC User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.2.1-rc1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/overloaded_record_update.html#:%7E:text=At%20this%20time%2C%20RebindableSyntax%20must%20be%20enabled%20when%20OverloadedRecordUpdate%20is%20and%20users%20are%20required%20to%20provide%20definitions%20for%20getField%20and%20setField.%20We%20anticipate%20this%20restriction%20to%20be%20lifted%20in%20a%20future%20release%20of%20GHC%20with%20builtin%20support%20for%20setField.) has this to say:

   > At this time, RebindableSyntax must be enabled when OverloadedRecordUpdate is and users are required to provide definitions for getField and setField. We anticipate this restriction to be lifted in a future release of GHC with builtin support for setField.

   The default `getField` can be imported from `GHC.Records`, but `setField` is not currently available, so you have to implement it yourself.

   Have fun!

Comment: Ah, OK, this make sense. The plot thickens! :-) Thanks Ari. It'll be great when GHC 9.2.1 is released.

Comment: Great, but also probably different :-). It goes without saying, I hope you're not using this code in production :-)

Comment: Definitely not using this in code in production right now. :-) This came out [this (controversial) experiment](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/p0pclw/haskell_methods/) I posted to the Haskell subreddit.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT 11/08: This answer is mostly incomplete and partly incorrect. See my other answer.*

As @alias explained, if you enable `RebindableSyntax`, the Prelude will not be automatically loaded. Nor will `GHC.Records`, normally loaded by and required by record syntax extensions.

You'll have to add this:

```
import Prelude
import GHC.GetRecords
```

Comment: Gosh, I could have sworn I tested your suggestion above and thus accepted the answer. However, now that I'm trying it again after adding `import GHC.Records`, I'm actually seeing this:
`Not in scope: ‘setField’` followed by 
`Perhaps you meant ‘getField’ (imported from GHC.Records)`.